# Validating forms returned by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

If i have a page which has an ajax link and that the code returns a that form needs validating, where do i put the validation code please. Say my form had this validation using the jquery validation plugin

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $("#basicForm").validate({

    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {

      // Clean up any tooltips for valid elements
      $.each(this.validElements(), function(index, element) {
        var $element = $(element);

        $element.data("title", "") // Clear the title - there is no error associated anymore
          .removeClass("error")
          .tooltip("destroy");
      });

      // Create new tooltips for invalid elements
      $.each(errorList, function(index, error) {
        var $element = $(error.element);

        $element.tooltip("destroy") // Destroy any pre-existing tooltip so we can repopulate with new tooltip content
          .data("title", error.message)
          .addClass("error")
          .tooltip(); // Create a new tooltip based on the error messsage we just set in the title
      });
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {

      var myselect = $('select[name=ddCustomers]');
      //alert(myselect.val());
      window.location.replace("customer.php?customer_id=" + myselect.val());
    }
  });
  $("#basicForm").removeAttr("novalidate");
});
```

where do i put it as the document.ready where i would normally out this code has already been called

I hope this makes sense

Could i have it on the page in the initial page load ready for when the form is returned

I've read i coud have the validation in the document.on function but dont really understand. Would i post something like this back with my ajax response for the validation

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#basicForm', function(){
    $("#basicForm").validate({
        submitHandler: function() {
        // do whatever you need here
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Thanks for your help. Its confusing and I cant find a decent example on google

EDIT

I know how to write the validation code for the dynamically generated forms so thanks for those answers but I am alright on that. The question is WHERE that code should i put it in the ajax return?
Perhaps i have a misconception but i am using jquery validate module (base assistance( and i have only ever seen the `form validate  method called in doc. ready on the first page - never an ajax postback

> document.ready

Options

1) Hard coded in page already writing for when form injected by ajax? not dynamic enough - the injected form is created dynamically so the validation may need to 
be
2) Add validation code to

> document.on

when i do ajax postback for the new form? Is this even possible? Im not a client side programmer.

I am bemused that such a common scenario doesnt have a design pattern. Though i have read postng back forms via ajax is bad practice as it can confuse the browser and now what ajax whs written for so perhaps that why i cant find a solution

thanks

Comment: I don't see any ajax in the code you posted. Basically, you want to validate as much as possible on the client side (using JavaScript). Once client side passes validation, then your ajax call should validate on the server side and if all is well, update your database. The client side validation is for user-experience, server side validation is for business logic and database compatibility.

Comment: i want ot validate it on the client side but i dont know where to put the code on the client side that would validate the form.

Comment: You can put that document.body style listener almost anywhere. Once you attach it to the body, it will listen for existing forms as well any forms that may be attached to the body in the future.

Comment: So would i add it on the first page making the ajax call or would i overwrite it in my ajax call as there is a opssibility it is dynamic? can i do that?

Comment: e.g. just add something like this under the new form

Comment: $(document.body).on('click', '#MyFormSubmitButton', function(){
       $("#MyformID").validate({
          
    });
 });

Comment: You should put your client side validation code in an event listener that will get triggered when a user attempts to submit the form. See posted answer.

Comment: cool - but this still comes with the injected html form

Comment: plus how do i aware you point from here

Answer (score 0):

I've coded and developed many web apps just with jquery, php being the server side script. The way I formed was to have the jquery code and html on the same page since jquery needs to check the html element and respond with the proper error message and sanitize all the data fields before I submit to the "form-process.php" for an example if that was the name of your server side script.

Have:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#basicForm', function(){
    $("#basicForm").validate({
        submitHandler: function() {
        // do whatever you need here
        } 
    }); 
});
```

code as the same page as say: create-username.html or create-username.php page 
html elements. Some prefer to have jquery on the bottom, depends on how you have your 
page structured, but I like to put the js on top from old practices although sometimes it doesn't apply to jquery.

include your tooltips code in the same block. I don't like to have jquery all over the place; incase of errors or if you need to modify in future reference it wouldn't be hard to pinpoint to edit, add or fix code. I hope this helps.

Comment: the website i have aopted has every single call back to the server on one page. the whole site is one page

Comment: By same page i meant have the validation code for the second form alreay on the page when it is loaded before the callback for the form but the form is dynamic so the validation should be too

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the validation plugin first and set up the rules you want. Then when a user submits the form, prevent the default form submission behavior and if all is validated successfully based on the criteria of the rules you set, you manually submit the form to the server using ajax.

```
 $('#basicForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
              required: true,
              email: true
          },
           field2: {
               required: true,
               minlength: 5
          }
      }
  });

$('document').on('submit', '#basicForm', function(e){   
    if($(this).valid()){
           //client side is valid, make ajax call
    }
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: I can just return this code is my ajax response for my new form and get it i the page of course

Comment: No, you shouldn't be returning javascript code in your ajax response.